# How to give coin to user in discord py?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord

I have a problem with giving points to a user.

```
def give_point(user): 
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM math")
    results = c.fetchall()
    for result in results:
        if result[0] == user:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
        


@client.command()
async def solved(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    if member.bot:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} is Bot")
    elif give_point(member.name) == "False":
        c.execute(f"INSERT INTO math VALUES({member.name}, 40, '{ctx.guild.id}')")
        await ctx.send("OK")
```

If the user wrote  !Solved [member] The user must get coin. But when I seeing leaderboard this command is not working. How can i solve this problem ?.
Please someone help me :).

Comment: The way you select the database should be `SELECT * FROM databaseName.tableName`, that could be the issue.

Comment: Does it give any error, have you tried debugging it? More info could help.

Comment: There is no error, but the data does not inserting in the database.

Comment: You need to commit your changes for them to be saved. This can be done with `con.commit()`, where `con` is your database connection (not cursor).